# Redundant Node Clean Up

Tags: java, algorithm, nodes, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to clean up a set of nodes that I have implemented in JAVA to create a Directed Acyclic Graph. I have a Java Set that has each of the nodes I want in my final graph, however some of the Node ID's are the same. When I try to combine nodes with the same ID I am running into issues if they have the same childList. As the childList is a JAVA Linked List, I cannot add or change a childList to one of my nodes without subsequently changing the children of the other node.

I am trying to dereference each of the Linked Lists so that I can change a Node's children without having a knock down affect, however I am struggling to find the code for it. For example, if you look below, when I attempt to combine the node Surday (with HashCode reference src.java.GNode@5) with the other node called Surday (reference src.java.GNode@3) by moving the children of one to the other, I cannot do this without changing the children of the Suday and Sunrday nodes as well(src.java.GNode@2 and src.java.GNode@1).

```
Node: Sunday Node HashCode Reference: src.java.GNode@0
Node: Sunrday Children: src.java.GNode@0  Children: src.java.GNode@1  
Node HashCode Reference: src.java.GNode@1

Node: Suday Children: src.java.GNode@0  Children: src.java.GNode@1  
Node HashCode Reference: src.java.GNode@2

Node: Surday Children: src.java.GNode@0  Children: src.java.GNode@1  
Node HashCode Reference: src.java.GNode@3

Node: Surday Children: src.java.GNode@1  Node HashCode Reference: src.java.GNode@4

Node: Surday Children: src.java.GNode@2  Node HashCode Reference: src.java.GNode@5

Node: Sturday Children: src.java.GNode@3  Node HashCode Reference: src.java.GNode@6

Node: Sturday Children: src.java.GNode@4  Node HashCode Reference: src.java.GNode@7

Node: Sturday Children: src.java.GNode@5  Node HashCode Reference: src.java.GNode@8

Node: Saturday Children: src.java.GNode@6  Children: src.java.GNode@7  Children: src.java.GNode@8  Node HashCode Reference: src.java.GNode@c
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I should fix this? I was thinking due to the need to change these nodes without any affect to the children list now, I could just put the children list into a string array, however the following code which I visualise my algorithm would be affected heavily.

Thank You.

Comment: A work around would be to leave all dependent lists alone and don't add or remove to them, just use them to add to other lists...

Comment: why are you not using a set? That would avoid the duplicates...

Comment: @JohnM some of the nodes have differing children, so if I were to implement in a set I would lose some data which I need, it’s ok though I have sorted my issue with a workaround